# Show color on full screen in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview, hstack, zstack

I'm trying to show red color in full screen.

If I use `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` the screen automatically becomes scrolling enabled, which I don't want. Can you please advise me how to show red color on full screen without scrolling and without stretching because i change the color to image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Sample code is given below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageSetup: View {

  @State private var tabSelection = 0

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
          ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("\(index)")
          }
        }
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
      .onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
  }
}
```

---

Output

[image]

Comment: You means it shouldn’t paginate after first launch ? Or it shouldn’t bounce?

Comment: i need paginate but i don't want bounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you wanted correctly, you are using `ZStack` and `Color` in wrong place. Your `body` should be like this code sample.

---

```
struct PageSetup: View {

  @State private var tabSelection = 0

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      getColorForPage().ignoresSafeArea()
      TabView (selection: $tabSelection) {
        ForEach(0..<5){ index in
          Text("\(index)")
        }
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
      .onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
      }
    }
  }

  func getColorForPage() -> Color {
    if tabSelection == 0 {
      return Color.red
    } else if tabSelection == 1 {
      return Color.blue
    } else {
      return Color.orange
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i want also change colour with like text 1 red, text 2 blue etc.. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see edited answer, and if it's okay for you please accept my answer.

Comment: You are right, i have implemented your code but it is not showing properly image from top and bottom can you please check my screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br8E6.png

Comment: Don't forget to add  `.ignoresSafeArea()` after your image. If you look at my code you will see that after `Color`